# Using Realm Framework in Today extension (CocoaPods)

Tags: cocoapods, swift2, realm

I am using realm.io as storage for some data. I want to share this data with my Today extension. I am using CocoaPods and I am wondering how I can share that Framework with both targets. My podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'RealmSwift'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'Alamofire'
```

I tried with this and it worked when building to device, but not when building to the iOS simulator. It returned the error 'ld: framework not found Pods':

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
   pod 'RealmSwift'
   pod 'Alamofire'
end

target 'App' do
    shared_pods
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'
end

target 'AppToday' do
    shared_pods
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Appreciate any help.

Brgds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Podfile looks correct and would work on a clean installation. But you found a bug in the user project integration in CocoaPods when migrating between different setups.

### Background info

If you don't explicitly specify a target in the Podfile, then CocoaPods will integrate with the first target in your project. This was your app target, which worked correct as long as it was the only one.

But now you're referencing explicitly to the targets. CocoaPods will create separate so called aggregate targets. Those are in the `Pods.xcodeproj` and named `Pods-App` and `Pods-AppToday`. These are static framework targets (from 0.39.beta.5), which are weak linked to your targets to help Xcode finding your dependencies in the Pods project. Because CocoaPods doesn't know anything about the previous Podfile when you run `pod install` (and it doesn't retain this information in the `Podfile.lock`), it doesn't remove the old aggregate target, which was named just `Pods` and it's product reference in your app target.

### Resolving the issue

- Select your project file in Xcode in the file navigator
- Select your app target in the left pane from the targets list
- Go to the **General** tab
- Remove `Pods.framework` from the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** pane

#### Expected state before

[image: Both aggregate target products: the old to remove and the new to keep]

#### How it should look like

[image: Just the new aggregate target product]

Comment: Excellent, that solved all of my problems! Thank you for a good explanation and guide. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'RealmSwift'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'Alamofire'
```

Add this line

```
link_with 'App', 'AppToday'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. Does this include all frameworks for both targets? I don't need MBProgressHUD in my Today-extension.

Comment: Yes, It's used  to share the same pods. But I think it will help you to test in simulator